# Take-while and take-nth in clojure

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, take

I'm trying to get n messages from a queue (using langohr). I have a working version but I would like to know if there is a better clojurist way of doing this:

```
(def not-nil? (complement nil?))

(defn get_message [queue] 
   (let [[_ payload] (lb/get ch queue)]
       (if (not-nil? payload)
         (String. payload "UTF-8"))))


(take 4 (take-while not-nil? (repeatedly (partial get_message "my_queue"))))
```

So I fetch up to N messages as long as there are messages in the queue.

Is there a better clojurist way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not-nil?` is the same as the built in function `some?` in clojure 1.6

The idiom is to use `-` in preference to `_` in Clojure binding names.

`(partial get_message "my_queue")` is better as `#(get-message "my_queue")` since you clearly have no intention of adding args

`(if (some? payload) (String. payload "UTF-8"))`

could be expressed as

`(some-> payload (String. "UTF-8"))`,

though you may want to reserve `some->` for longer chaining, it's still more concise in this case.

So, putting this all together:

```
(defn get-message [queue]
  (let [[_ payload] (lb/get ch queue)]
    (some-> payload (String. "UTF-8"))))

(take 4 (take-while some? (repeatedly #(get-message "my_queue"))))
```

Comment: I am trying to use RabbitMQ on my localhost, but having hard time with it, can you give me any pointers regarding that

Comment: @PankajNimgade Can you describe more your problem?